# how to test your projectes that are signed?

Tags: .net, fitnesse

I need to use fitnesse on my signed project. and that causes me some problems.

I've tried to make my test assembly signed.
but there is a reference to fit and fitsharp needed in the project.

how do I get a signed fit and fitsmart dll's?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the source at github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp and build signed dlls